# Logstash-logger: Rails stacktrace splitting into multiple json lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logstash

I'm using logstash-logger to log my rails logs. It works for most cases, but when something goes wrong (ie; I get an error) Rails produces a stack trace. But the logger logs it into multiple Json lines. How can I solve this?

I'm attaching a small part of the log here

> {"message":"Started GET \"/\" ... }
>
> {"message":"  ",  ... }
>
> {"message":"ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] \"/\"):" ... }
>
> {"message":"vendor/bundle/ruby/2 ... }

This is single stack trace, but the logger is logging it as multiple logs.

This is my logstash-logger configuration

```
logstash_logger = LogStashLogger.new(
  type: :file,
  path: "log/#{Rails.env}.log",
  sync: true
)
if "#{Rails.env}" != "development"
  config.logger = logstash_logger
end
```

Comment: Solve what? ...

Comment: Splitting a single stacktrace to multiple lines

Comment: The stack trace is getting split up, I can't debug when I get multiple errors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [mcve] of your problem, and for more tips see: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As your question is currently phrased, we don't know what you have tried so far, or how to reproduce your problem.

Comment: do you have an update?

Comment: I found out that there is a json field `tags` in the all the json lines, this is same for all the json lines in the same stack trace. I will have to search using that tag to get the complete stacktrace @FabrizioBertoglio

Answer (score 0):

> ## [Custom Log Fields](https://github.com/dwbutler/logstash-logger#custom-log-fields)
>
> LogStashLogger by default will log a JSON object with the format below.

```
{
  "message":"Some Message",
  "@timestamp":"2015-01-29T10:43:32.196-05:00",
  "@version":"1",
  "severity":"INFO",
  "host":"hostname"
}
```

then I read

> ## [Rails Integration](https://github.com/dwbutler/logstash-logger#rails-integration)
>
> Supports Rails 4 and 5.
>
> By default, every Rails log message will be written to logstash in LogStash::Event JSON format.
>
> For minimal, more-structured logstash events, try one of the following gems:

[lograge](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge)

[yarder](https://github.com/rurounijones/yarder)

> Currently these gems output a JSON string, which LogStashLogger then parses. Future versions of these gems could potentially have deeper integration with LogStashLogger (e.g. by directly writing LogStash::Event objects).

Did you dig deep in this documentation because they do on purpose give you a `json` format

Answer (score 0):

For getting rails logs in `json` format with multiple rows you should use `type: :json_lines`.